World War II movie from the 70s that depicts the training of a Japanese kamikaze pilot
My father watched this movie in the 70's, but he didn't remember the name and I couldn't find it on the internet with the information I have, so I guess it's an obscure movie.
The only information I have regarding the movie is that it showed the training of a Japanese kamikaze pilot and that apparently was a big part of the movie. I don't know if there was actual combat but he asked me to search for keywords like: "empire of the rising sun" and just "rising sun". I don't know if the poster have a rising sun on it. Unfortunately my father passed away so that's about all the info I have.
I showed him a movie called "Zero Pilot" but it wasn't it. Other than that I couldn't find anything.
Thank you in advance. I know the info may be a little scarce, and I'm afraid the mentioned parts may not be the main subject of the movie.

This is a Japanese movie, I guess?

@mattiav27: Unfortunately, I don't know if it's a Japanese movie.

A little cumbersome to search, but here's a link to the wikipedia list of WW II movies. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_World_War_II_films

@dbugger: Thank you for the list. I just went through this whole list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Pacific_War_films but couldn't find it. I'm going to try that one. I don't really care if it's cumbersome to search. I just want to find that movie. If I can't find it online I'm going to find out in what cinema he saw the movie and try to contact the owners maybe. I'm going to keep this updated in case I find the movie for future reference. Thank you.

Oh, I was assuming American. My bad. When you think about it, though, even globally your search (if it IS a movie) is not that extreme: From about 1945-1980, WWII movies about the War in the Pacific, eliminating Pearl Harbor and Manzanar.

From a historical perspective, it would have to be set after the Battle of Midway, or its likely anachronistic.

I'll go for the simplest explanation...
(even though the film was from the 80's)
Maybe it was Empire of the sun?
Although not specifically about the training of kamikaze pilots, when the protagonist in an internment camp, it borders an airfield where pilots are seen leaving and never returning. The protagonist befriends a Japanese boy who (as a last resort) is given training and a 'plane.

There is actual "training" shown. They do not have airplanes to train in so they have wooden mock-ups of the control stick and they all go through motions of flying, like kata. They don't have to learn to land. The fact that they are kamikazi is also shown by their white scarves and ceremonial accessories and other cultural aspects of the unit and their training. If I remember correctly, the japnese boy is finally given a mission but when he tries to take off his plane fails and he is very upset that he can't sacrifice for the emperor.

最後の神風
Here goes a shot in the dark, but could it be the following 1970 Japanese movie about 24 Japanese kamikaze pilots at the end of the war:

Saigo no Tokkoutai (The Last Kamikaze) (1970) - Fictional account of 24 kamikaze planes and 12 escort planes that make attack on final day of war. Commander of kamikaze unit makes successful hit on aircraft carrier even though wounded. When lieutenant who commands escort planes hears of Japan's surrender, he flies alone in a Zero as the last kamikaze. Famous actor Ken Takakura, who plays a surviving kamikaze pilot in Hotaru (Firefly), plays role of commander of kamikaze unit in this movie. - Kamikaze Images 

IMBd has the following review on this movie:

This could have been a yakuza or a samurai film. It matters of honour, sacrifice, friendship, family...A great film, painful, awful, terrific story of the authentic kamikaze fly boys in the end of the war against USA. The characters are powerful to explain to us, non Japanese fellows, what honour means. We now understand how these guys chose to give their lives for their country. And we watch their doubts, their interrogations before getting into their planes. We see for instance this young guy who could not do it because his old mother, he just thought that he had to take care of her. And when he tells her that afterwards, she says that she is ashamed of him. Painful at the most. But, I repeat, so outstanding. We find here the same actors as we usually see in yakuza movies: Koji Tsuruta, Ken Takakura - the most famous Japanese actor in the Occident after Toshiro Mifune, and Bunta Sugawara. Only Ando Noburu is missing. The director Junya Sato made many yakuzas stuff. I have plenty of them, and maybe I'll comment them later. - A real gem from the Rising Sun 


OK, I'm going to take another stab at this: Maybe it wasn't a movie, it was the TV show "Black Sheep Squadron"?
This was a short-lived (2 seasons) TV show in the '70s by Stephen J. Cannell starring Robert Conrad and John Laroquette dramatizing the adventures of the actual Black Sheep Squadron, which gained some notoriety during the war. 
The season 2, episode 1 episode (historically inaccurately) depicts the formation of the Kamikaze as Japan's desperate attempt to get past the devilishly effective fighters who are the show's heroes.
The episode can currently be viewed on YouTube, and at about 5 minutes you can see the idea presented, at about 19:30, the first recruit, about 30:30, their first mission briefing, and finally at 37:10, the after mission briefing on the success.
This was a very "Dad" show, too, and in my experience, TV shows tend to be harder to identify in retrospect than movies. An American WWII movie in the '70s: Well, there actually weren't all that many, and they tended toward Big Budget extravaganzas with lots of set pieces: The aforementioned Tora! Tora! Tora! which bombed (heh) and so had its fighting footage reused for Midway. A Bridge Too Far, Patton, MacArthur, stuff like that, which you'd probably remember.

First name and you just kept going.  Boyington's memoir is an interesting read, https://www.amazon.com/Black-Sheep-Gregory-Pappy-Boyington/dp/0553263501/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1470691762

That went on the reading list, thanks!

Thank you for your answer. It is possible it wasn't a movie, I'm going to ask my uncle for clues. I see most of these Japanese movies didn't make to the Occident, so if it was Japanese I guess it would have to be very exceptional.

Seldom did foreign movies—much less foreign language movies—make it to the USA prior to the '70s. The King of Indie/B movies, Roger Corman, started making hay with this in the '70s, but the only Japanese-ish movie he distributed was Kurosawa's Dersu Uzala, which is not about the war. Even having seen this would be fairly outré, big-city hardcore movie fan stuff.
